# Scraping data- attributes from web page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am needing some assistance on using python to **scrape** some data- attributes form a site. I have tried using `lxml` and `requests` with no luck and have looked online and I found some articles about using beautiful soup. The only problem is I am not sure how.

Here is what I would like to scrape.

```
<div class="card-body ">

<div class="card-entry" data-var1="0" data-var2="1" data-var3="20" data-var4="3" data-var5="9">… </div>">
<div class="card-entry" data-var1="1" data-var2="2" data-var3="9" data-var4="2" data-var5="7">… </div>">
<div class="card-entry" data-var1="2" data-var2="3" data-var3="1" data-var4="3" data-var5="3">…</div>
<div class="card-entry" data-var1="3" data-var2="4" data-var3="5" data-var4="2" data-var5="9">…</div>
```

I am trying to get the `data-var5` value out but I have no idea how. Hope someone can help.

Regards,

Hazza

Comment: Its returning a blank list s = tree.xpath('//div[@class="card-entry"]/@data-var5')
print(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `select`. you can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div class="card-entry" data-var1="0" data-var2="1" data-var3="20" data-var4="3" data-var5="9">… </div>
<div class="card-entry" data-var1="1" data-var2="2" data-var3="9" data-var4="2" data-var5="7">… </div>
<div class="card-entry" data-var1="2" data-var2="3" data-var3="1" data-var4="3" data-var5="3">…</div>
<div class="card-entry" data-var1="3" data-var2="4" data-var3="5" data-var4="2" data-var5="9">…</div> 
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
data_var = soup.select('div[data-var5]')

for data in data_var:
    print("data-var5: " + data['data-var5'])
```

Output will be:

```
data-var5: 9
data-var5: 7
data-var5: 3
data-var5: 9
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="card-entry" data-var1="0" data-var2="1" data-var3="20" data-var4="3" data-var5="9">… </div>
<div class="card-entry" data-var1="1" data-var2="2" data-var3="9" data-var4="2" data-var5="7">… </div>
<div class="card-entry" data-var1="2" data-var2="3" data-var3="1" data-var4="3" data-var5="3">…</div>
<div class="card-entry" data-var1="3" data-var2="4" data-var3="5" data-var4="2" data-var5="9">…</div> 
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
divs = soup.find_all("div", "card-entry")
for div in divs:
    print(div["data-var5"])
```