# Scraping data - attributes from a web page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello i am new in web scraping and i have a problem. I want to **scrape** data from this html code: [image]

I want to have the data that belongs inside the

```
<tr> .. </tr>
```

tag.

My code is shown as below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
rows = soup.select('tr[data-row]')

print(rows)
```

I am inspired by this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62392156/scraping-data-attributes-from-web-page), but it's returning a empty array. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Just looked at the html and it seems like the attribute `data-row` is being added at the client side. Which is why your select query returns an empty array

Comment: FYI 'to scrap' means to throw away like rubbish. The correct term is __scrape__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `pandas` to make your web-scraping life (a bit) easier?

Here's how:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_html(requests.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/').text, flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df)
df.to_csv("basketball_table.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: indeed, that's make my life easier thank you

Comment: why use requests here? Bit redundant. simply use the url and pandas will do that part: `df = pd.read_html('https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/')`

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comment, it looks as if the attribute `data-row` is being added at the client side - I couldn't find it in the HTML.

A quick and easy way to fix this would be to change your css selector. I came up with something like this

```
rows = soup.select('tr')
for row in rows:
    if row.th.attrs['data-stat']=='season' and 'scope' in row.th.attrs:
        print(row)
```

Comment: This is helpful and the solution is correct thank you